# Getting error: "You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected" without react-native debugger

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, graphql, redux-observable

I'm a newbie and I have the code provided below which work excellent with react-native debugger connected, but without the debugger, I'm getting the error. Error connected to that line: 
`return from((execute(link, operation) as unknown) as Subscribable<GraphQLResponse<{ login: User }>>)
      .pipe(responseInterceptor('login'));`

But I don't know how to fix it.

Full code of my request:

```
login(userInput: LoginInput) {
    const operation = {
      query: gql`
        mutation Login($userInput: LoginInput) {
          login(input: $userInput) {
            _id
            authToken
            email
            status
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: { userInput },
    };

    return from((execute(link, operation) as unknown) as Subscribable<GraphQLResponse<{ login: User }>>)
      .pipe(responseInterceptor('login'));
  }
```

Comment: What does `responseInterceptor('login')` return?

Comment: Error if it is
`export function responseInterceptor(key: string) {
  return (obs: Observable<{ data: any; errors: any }>) => {
    return obs.pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        if (response.errors) {
          return throwError(response.errors);
        }
        return of(response.data);
      }),
      pluck(key),
    );
  };
}`